# Convert MongoDB query format to SQL query

Tags: java, sql, json, mongodb

What I need to do is that I need to convert `MongoDB` query format (left of =>) that is in `JSON` string to corresponding `SQL` query `WHERE` clause (right of =>)

```
{ status: "D" }`  **=>** `WHERE status = "D"
{ status: { $in: [ "A", "D" ] } }  **=>**  WHERE status in ("A", "D")
{ $or: [ { status: "A" }, { qty: { $lt: 30 } } ] }  **=>** WHERE status = "A" OR qty < 30
{ $and: [ { status: "A" }, { qty: { $lt: 30 } } ] } **=>** WHERE status = "A" AND qty < 30
```

Can you please gide me any framework/library that I can use for it? Projetc is in `Java` language.

Comment: framework/library to convert MongoDB to SQL? I'm not sure If I understand your question correctly

Answer (score 1):

You could try the npm package [mongo-to-sql-converter](https://github.com/gordonbusyman/mongo-to-sql-converter), which was designed for this purpose.

Adapting the docs for your question:

```
var mongoToSqlConverter = require("mongo-to-sql-converter")

const MongoDBQuery = "db.user.find({ $or: [ { status: 'A' }, { qty: { $lt: 30 } } ] });"

const SQLQuery = mongoToSqlConverter.convertToSQL(MongoDBQuery, true)

console.log(SQLQuery)
```

Putting the above in a script and running with node in the terminal results in

```
✗ node mongo.js 

SELECT * FROM user WHERE (status = 'A' OR qty < 30);
```

which seems to be what you're after.

Comment: Better learn how to write queries in MongoDB. This converter covers only the **very basic** functions. Stuff like `NOT IN`, `=ANY`, `<>ALL` or regular expressions are not converted.

Comment: The solution covers the examples provided in the question.

Comment: No. There are libraries to get node code working with java (e.g. [trireme](https://github.com/apigee/trireme)) or you could port the code to java as there is very [little of it](https://github.com/gordonBusyman/mongo-to-sql-converter/blob/master/src/converter.js).